# Adding and Removing Styles to li group using Angular 2

Tags: css, angular

```
<ul>
<li (click)="AddColor($event)">ONE</li>
<li (click)="AddColor($event)">TWO</li>
<li (click)="AddColor($event)">THREE</li>
</ul>

AddColor(e){

e.srcElement.style.color="blue"

}
```

I have the above list when i click any one of the li item out of 3, the clicked label color should be changed. when i click another all item colors should be revert back to original and change color of current clicked item.

Comment: Can u add a working fiddle for your quewstion

Comment: @AravindReddy: https://plnkr.co/edit/2AZ2s6CHr6Hm1W8lJhZA?p=preview

Comment: Change for  [class.blue]="activeLink === i" an (click)="activeLink = i"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mehdi said, you should not access DOM directly untill there is a need.

> Always keep in mind, drive your view with data rather than accessing
>   DOM directly

```
I have forked and working snippet https://plnkr.co/edit/fgINMc?p=preview
```

Comment: Performance wise, I never attach a method to a "permanent event" like [class.bold-class]="isActiveLink(link)  because, Angular will be continuously  calling this.isActiveLink to see if value has changed. I would use a data binding variable instead that the selectLink method can update so that Angular propagates the change to the view once it has happened. if you want to check this behaviour, put a breakpoint inside isActiveLink

Answer (score 0):

When using Angular, you don't want to directly manipulate the DOM element. Rather let angular deal with it. 
In your example, you can generate your list from an array you declare in the code like so

```
export class YourClass{
   links:any;
   activeLink = -1;
   //...
   constructor(){
      this.links = ['ONE','TWO','THREE']
   }
   //...
}
```

and then in your template you could have :

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let link of links; let i = index" 
       (click)="activeLink = i"
       [ngClass]="activeLink == i? 'blue' : '' " >
  </li>
</ul>
```

and declare a css class blue :

```
.blue{
   color:blue;
}
```